# strdupa() in C - Dangers and Duplicates

Tags: c, strdup

I make programs in C. I read about the `strdup()` function. From what I could tell, the `strdup()` function allocates space while the `strcpy()` does not. But the problem with `strdup()` is it allocates space but does not free it. `strdupa()` allocates and frees space. But at some places I read that the `strdupa()` function is dangerous. It would be helpful if someone could tell me why `strdupa()` is dangerous. Also, when I tried to run a program in my Open Suse 12.1 32 bit system, *gcc*, gave an error which told that `strdupa()` does not exist. If `strdupa()` is a dangerous function, can someone tell me the duplicate of `strdupa()` and the headers to use when using the function.

Comment: "But the problem with strdup() is it allocates space but does not free it". `malloc` also has this "problem". The point is that it is not a problem per se because the calling code can `free` it. Some people argue it can lead to memory leaks if the coder forgets to free the memory. But in many cases, you actually do want the memory to persist beyond the current function so not freeing the memory is in fact what is wanted.

Comment: So you're saying using the strdup() function is better than using strdupa()

Comment: No, I'm saying the right tool for the right job.

Comment: So you mean to say that for copying a string to another and allocating memory automatically, strdup() is better.

Comment: It's not a question of "better" or "worse".  The point is, if you use "strdup()", then you need to be aware that it did a "malloc()", and it's *your* responsibility to "free()".  This is *exactly* the behavior you want and need if the string needs to persist outside of the function where you duplicated it.  As an additional note, ["strdup()"](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup) is a Posix standard, "strdupa()" isn't.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [`strdupa()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdupa) function is documented to use the [`alloca()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/alloca) function to allocate memory.  That means its memory is freed when the function returns.  The `alloca()` function is not singularly portable; the `strdupa()` function is likewise not all that portable.

The manual page documents that the `strdupa()` function is only available when you compile with `-D_GNU_SOURCE`, or if you use `gcc -std=gnu11` or something similar.

If you need to access the memory after the function that calls `strdupa()` returns, then you cannot use `strdupa()` — `strdup()` is necessary.  If you're worried about portability, you probably use `strdup()`, though even that is only defined by POSIX ([`strdup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html)) and not by Standard C.  Note that `strdup()` is part of [TR 24731-2: Extensions to the C Library - Part II: Dynamic allocation functions](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/projects).  AFAIK, `alloca()` is not part of either POSIX or the proposed extensions to the Standard C library.

---

> Is there any danger in using 'strdupa()'?

It depends on your definition of 'danger'.  Yes.  If there isn't enough space on the stack for the string, then `strdupa()` will fail when `strdup()` won't.  There are those who are not enamoured of `alloca()` and therefore they are not keen on code that uses `alloca()`.  The `alloca()` manual page has an extensive set of notes about the problems, one of which is that you can't tell when `alloca()` has failed.

> Is there a tool to check for `alloca()` failures — such as `valgrind` for memory leaks?

You look for core dumps; if the program crashes, it was perhaps because of an `alloca()` allocation failure.  Using [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) might spot the problem; you still can't reliably recover from the problem, though, and you probably won't have your production code running under `valgrind`, so it is at most a diagnostic aid.  If you want reliable behaviour, use `strdup()` — and accept that you need to manually free the allocated memory.

#### From the manual page for `alloca()`

> **Notes**
>   The `alloca()` function is machine- and compiler-dependent. For certain applications, its use can improve efficiency compared to the use of malloc(3) plus free(3). In certain cases, it can also simplify memory deallocation in applications that use longjmp(3) or siglongjmp(3). Otherwise, its use is discouraged.
>
> Because the space allocated by `alloca()` is allocated within the stack frame, that space is automatically freed if the function return is jumped over by a call to longjmp(3) or siglongjmp(3).
>
> Do not attempt to free(3) space allocated by alloca()!
>
> **Notes on the GNU version**
>   Normally, gcc(1) translates calls to `alloca()` with inlined code. This is not done when either the `-ansi`, `-std=c89`, `-std=c99`, or the `-fno-builtin` option is given (and the header `<alloca.h>` is not included). But beware! By default the glibc version of `<stdlib.h>` includes `<alloca.h>` and that contains the line:
>
> ```
> #define alloca(size)   __builtin_alloca (size)
> ```
>
> with messy consequences if one has a private version of this function.
>
> The fact that the code is inlined means that it is impossible to take the address of this function, or to change its behavior by linking with a different library.
>
> The inlined code often consists of a single instruction adjusting the stack pointer, and does not check for stack overflow. Thus, there is no NULL error return.
>
> **Bugs**
>   There is no error indication if the stack frame cannot be extended. (However, after a failed allocation, the program is likely to receive a SIGSEGV signal if it attempts to access the unallocated space.)
>
> On many systems `alloca()` cannot be used inside the list of arguments of a function call, because the stack space reserved by `alloca()` would appear on the stack in the middle of the space for the function arguments.

Comment: Is there any danger in using 'strdupa()'

Comment: @Screwdriver "The alloca() function returns a pointer to the beginning of the allocated space.  If the allocation causes stack overflow, program behavior is undefined.", this besides the "no use after return" given in the answer.

Comment: It depends on your definition of 'danger'.  Yes.  If there isn't enough space on the stack for the string, then `strdupa()` will fail when `strdup()` won't.  There are those who are not enamoured of `alloca()` and therefore they are not keen on code that uses `alloca()`.  The `alloca()` manual page (linked in the answer) has an extensive set of notes about the problems, one of which is that you can't tell when `alloca()` has failed.

Comment: Is there a tool to check for 'alloca()' failures. Such as 'valgrind' for memory leaks?

Comment: You look for core dumps; if the program crashes, it was perhaps because of an `alloca()` allocation failure.  Using [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) might spot the problem; you still can't reliably recover from the problem, though, and you probably won't have your production code running under `valgrind`, so it is at most a diagnostic aid.  If you want reliable behaviour, use `strdup()` — and accept that you need to manually free the allocated memory.

Comment: Is there a function which is safe as strdup() and allocates and frees space automatically?

Comment: Succinctly, no.  Not in C.  You can do it in C++ by creating an appropriate object with a destructor so that the memory is released when the object is destroyed, with no need for an explicit call to release the memory.  But C++ is not C.