# strdupa() implementation for Visual C

Tags: c, visual-studio, gcc, alloca

I am trying to port a C (not C++) program from GCC to Visual Studio.

The GCC specific function strdupa() is widely used in this program.
Is there any way to implement this function for Visual C.

PS. I understand that it uses alloca() and it is unsafe. But it works very well on GCC now and I think it is safer to implement the same function in one place then change the logic of program. I also don't want performance to decrease.

Comment: Well, according to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/alloca?view=vs-2019), there is a function equivalent to `alloca()`, which you could use to implement your own `strdupa()`. However, it is marked as deprecated and the suggested replacement doesn't behave in the same way (it might allocate on the stack or on the heap, and therefore requires calling a free function, so it is not a drop-in replacement)

Comment: @FelixG I understand that visual c has its own equivalent of alloca, but how to implement strdupa()? How to avoid freeing of memory when I return from my own implementation of strdupa()?

Comment: I suggest to create a macro. The macro can allocate space on local stack. It should work as an inline function (that should be the case also for `strdupa` to use local stack).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd implement it as a macro:

```
#define strdupa(a) strcpy((char*)alloca(strlen(a) + 1), a)
```

That way it is not in a function and so the alloca'd string won't be freed prematurely.

---

**Note:** From [man](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/alloca.3.html#BUGS):

> On many systems `alloca()` **cannot be used inside the list of arguments of a function call**, because the stack space reserved by `alloca()` would appear on the stack in the middle of the space for the function arguments.

… i.e. (from "[GNU C Library Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Variable-Size-Automatic.html)"):

> Do not use `alloca` inside the arguments of a function call—*you will get unpredictable results*, … . An example of **what to avoid** is `foo(x, alloca(4), y)`.

Comment: Yes, I think this is the solution. I will use it! But I am just curious, if there any way to implement it as function?

Comment: @Sandro yes you could do that, but that implies a lot of platform specific stuff including assembly code. Look at the source code of `alloca` which is available somewhere in the Windows SDK installed on your computer.

Comment: @Sandro also interesting information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33728005/898348

Answer (score 0):

My way to implement it as function. Not sure that it is safe, but it seems it works:

```
__forceinline char* strdupa(const char* s) {
    return strcpy((char*)_alloca(strlen(s) + 1), s);
}
```

But I think macro it a better way than using __forceinline